# How to make a python file un-editable and un-viewable the code?

Tags: python-3.x, privacy

I want to make my python file un-editable and anyone should not be able to view code. Client should only be able to run the python file not view the code.

Comment: Is said Python file a script behind a web server? Your question makes more sense to me in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think if that it possible. But what you could do it compile it to the platform specific executable format such as .exe for windows. You could use [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) for that

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make the file read only but if you need to make the file executable it needs read and execute permission.As the interpreter needs to read the file to execute it.
You can make the file read only and executable by using the `chmod` command in unix based systems.

You can refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16623/file-permission-execute-only).